# Update the existing content having custom field as GUID

Tags: 7, feeds

I want to update the contents view feeds. I have set the custom field as GUID in Node Mapping. So when importing it via csv in feeds it makes the unique field as guid and sets the guid in field value.

But if I add a content manually by node/add/content_type and the update it via feeds module it creates a new content. It means GUID for the manually created node is not set.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: When you manually create the content can you not just manually set the GUID field to the unique identifier?

Comment: Did the same using `db_insert`.